# initialize my class object using "=" java

Tags: java

I want to initialize objects of MyClass using "=" sign.

> Ex. String a = "hello";
>   I want to do
>   `MyClass a = 30;`

here is the Class I have written using constructor

```
public class Duration {
    private long seconds = 0;

    public Duration(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Such initialization is only possible for special classes - String and the wrappers of numeric primitive types (Integer, Double, ...).